# react jest confirming snapshot change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am newbie at React and I can not find a solution for a simple problem. 
I am using `create-react-app` and I succeed to operate jest snapshot test. Then, for trying I changed `render()` function's inside. Now jest said me `× has a valid snapshot (5ms)` (I know it is normal.) and it says me:

> 1 snapshot test failed in 1 test suite. Inspect your code changes or
>   press `u` to update them.

I don't know how can I update it. I tried to pressing u, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> and other combinations. But nothing changed in there. I know it is silly question but How can I update them?

Comment: How do you run the test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can update the snapshots in two ways:

1. run `npm test` and then in the interactive shell press `u`
2. run `npm test -u`, the `-u` flag tells jest to update snapshots.

You could change `npm` by `yarn` if you are using yarn

Comment: In my case I had to run `npm test -- -u` for the snapshots to update. Probably something that eventually was changed / updated by jest